# Python. Нужно число от остатка

Tags: python

```
def calc_stat(listened):  # от англ. calculate statistics, посчитать статистику
    listenedstatistics = 0
    for i in listened:
        listenedstatistics += i
    minutes = listenedstatistics // 60
    seconds = listenedstatistics 
    return (f'Вы прослушали {len(listened)} песен, общей продолжительностью {minutes} минут и {seconds} секунд') # напишите код функции calc_stat
print(calc_stat([193, 148, 210, 144, 174, 159, 163, 189, 230, 204]))
```

Собственно мне нужно получить остаток от `listenedstatistics // 60`, то есть секунды. Условие: не использовать %

Comment: гугл -> "питон операторы", гугл -> "питон остаток деления"

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что автор не предпринял ни малейших усилий, чтобы найти ответ на свой вопрос.

Comment: Там условие стоит, чтобы не использовать %

Comment: Тогда придется вспомнить элементарную формулу из начальной школы. Или догадаться до нее самостоятельно.

Comment: http://www.cleverstudents.ru/numbers/division_of_integers_with_remainder.html#:~:text=%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BC%20%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA,%3Da%E2%88%92b%C2%B7c.
Остаток от деления целого числа a на целое число b, когда известны делимое, делитель и неполное частное, используя формулу d=a−b·c.

Comment: divmod() - получишь и остаток, и результат деления

Answer (score 6):

```
minutes = listenedstatistics // 60
seconds = listenedstatistics 
z = seconds - (minutes*60) # Остаток
```